# If NP in BPP then NP equals RP

Tags: reference-request, complexity-classes, approximation

I am looking for a reference to the fact that if NP is included in BPP then NP is equal to RP. See for instance these links:

- https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/80509
- http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/cmc/cw3_solns.pdf
- https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~lyuu/complexity/2011/20120103s.pdf

I know that this is folklore, but I'd still like to cite something that is *published* and where this would be *properly proved*.

Comment: At this point in history, I don't know if this needs a citation, e.g. it is regularly given as an exercise. (I also don't know if there is such a citation, or if it was *always* just an exercise.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An actual factual reference is

K. Ko. Some observations on the probabilistic algorithms and NP-hard problems. Information Processing Letters, 14(1):39–43, 1982.

(When I first saw this result --- I don't remember where it was now --- it was called "Ko's Theorem". Googling suggests that another theorem has that name as well...)

Comment: Nice - I didn't know it actually existed in the literature!